# Allowing users to choose between a public and private profile. Better way to display this in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

I am making it so users can choose to allow their profiles to be public or only allowed to registered users.

Here are the steps that I took:

```
rails g migration AddIs_publicToUsers is_public:boolean
rake db:migrate
```

I have the :is_public to default=> true in my db

Then I added this into the user.rb model

```
attr_accessible :is_public
```

Now I'm trying to create the view but would it be better to do this using radioboxes instead of a checkbox?

```
<%= f.label :is_public, "Set Profile as Private" %>
      <%= f.check_box :is_public, :checked => false %>
```

The problem with above is that after users check their profile as private and they come back to the page, it doesn't stay checked which means that users aren't able to make their profile public again.

Finally, how do I ensure that is_public is referring to non-signed in users vs. sign-in users? For example, if is_public is true, then all people including signed in and non-signed in can view the profile. However, if is_public is false, then only signed in users of the website can view.

Comment: Your :is_public, :checked => false is forcing it to always display false. You want to set :checked to the Boolean value of the property.

Comment: Oh, I thought that :checked meant that was what checking it was setting the value to. Given the other answer, I plan to switch over to radio buttons instead which goes back to the original question. What would the view code for that look like for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really multiple questions in one.

#### Radio vs Checkbox

Given that this appears to be a mandatory and binary choice with a default value, radio buttons are going to be your best bet. As a tip, make sure that your labels are set correctly so the user can click on the label and doesn't have to find the radio button itself with their mouse (which is tiny).

#### Radio buttons not updating

If the radio buttons are not updating after the form is submitting, the user's input is getting lost somewhere. Check the params being submitted to see if the controller is receiving them, then make sure they are translated into the saved record. If the record is being updated, make sure your radio buttons are reflecting the database value in the form itself.

#### Signed-in users vs. non-signed-in users

My recommendation is to create a `before_filter` on the profiles controller, which checks the value of `is_public`, checks whether the user is signed in, then redirects non-authenticated users wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks, how can I make it so that if the radio button is checked for "private" and the user hits save, that this sets their profile as private and vice versa if they want to set it back to public? FYI - by the checkbox/radio button not updating, what I meant was that after a user leaves the page and comes back, I'd like the page to have whatever option the user selected to show. I will look more into this

Comment: @johbones Your radio button should be sending a parameter to your server when it is checked. Look for this parameter and use your controller to save your `is_public` field accordingly.